# How reliable is ```train_test_split```? Is there a way to optimize it?

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn, train-test-split

Using `train_test_split` is a common practice while building a Machine Learning model. Nevertheless, partitioning your dataset to get train and test samples is an specially delicate issue.

If you trust on pure randomness, the output might be representative of the correlation(s) that you are trying to look for. Or might not. It could even ‘find’ correlations that do not exist.

**Is there a way to ensure that `train_test_split` is doing its job properly?**

Just for the sake of suggestion, you could use an auxiliary Random Forest model, let's say like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

"""
We will build a dummy Random Forest model, just trying to extract as many information as possible from our dataset.
We assume that the more information is extracted, the greater the Out-Of-Bag Score will be.
Please note that max_depth is set to a low value (3) because we would like to discard the noisy samples, not to analyze the samples exhaustively.
"""

dummy = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=3, max_samples=0.8, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True)

dataset = make_circles(n_samples=150, noise=0.3, factor=0.3)

def auxPartitioner(n):

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(p, q, random_state=n, test_size=0.3)

    scaler = RobustScaler().fit(X_train)

    normalized_train_X = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

    auxRF = dummy.fit(normalized_train_X, y_train)

    print(auxRF.oob_score_)

    return auxRF.oob_score_


p, q = dataset

"""
Now we will search a number between 0 and 199 (or whatever interval) which maximizes the OOB Score of the dummy Random Forest, when is used as the seed of random_state.
That could indicate a good degree of correlation in the output sample.
"""

n = max(range(200), key=auxPartitioner) 
print(n)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(p, q, random_state=n, test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. How would *you* characterize the "job" that train-test-split is intended to do?  Have you researched our (many) threads about [situations where this approach is used?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=train+test+split)

Comment: @whuber Just splitting the dataset in such a way that minimizes the level of noise.

Comment: Q: "Is there a way to ensure that train_test_split is doing its job properly?"
A: One of the most reliable ways is to have data, lots and lots of data.

Answer (score 2):

The aim of a train/test split is to estimate true model performance. To do this in an unbiased way, the test data needs to be independent of the training data. If rows are independent, then a random split like `train_test_split()` will achieve this.

However, if the rows show additional structure like groups (multiple rows per patient/client/visitor etc.), or temporal dependence, then you need an other way to do the splits, e.g., via Scikit-Learn's

- `GroupShuffleSplit()` for grouped splits,
- `TimeSeriesSplit()` for time series, or
- `PredefinedSplit()` for custom splits.

Check [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection) for an overview of the splitter classes.

#### Edit

The larger the data, the more stable the estimated performance.
With only 150 observations, variance will be very high, and you might switch to nested/repeated cross-validation, or the method suggested by Frank in the comments. It stays important to respect row structure in these options.

Comment: It may be worth spelling out what some of these do to attempt to act like new previously unseen data, so for example on time series, it is conventional to use the most recent data as the test set.  For multiple observations per individual, it depends on whether you hope to use your model to make predictions in new circumstances for individuals you have previously seen or predictions for individuals you have not seen before.

Comment: Split sample validation is not stable enough to be trusted unless the sample size is perhaps > 20,000 if Y is binary (less if Y is continuous).  For a discussion see https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate.html .  This is why resampling methods are usually recommended (100 repeats of 10-fold cross validation or several hundred bootstrap resamples).

Comment: Good point @Frank

Comment: No good model can be produced out of a dataset, _**if there's no information contained on it.**_ So, any effort made to _improve the dataset consistency,_ will likely improve the outcoming models. In addition to the collection of more data, of course.